# jQuery mobile xml/Rss data reader to native app

Tags: jquery-mobile, rss

I have a blog with rss data feed. I have made it work on jqerymobile. I wonder how can i make it a native android and ios app now.
Any help appreciated
Kristtee

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with Cordova. Have a look at Phonegap/Cordova -> [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/)